# Ajax call does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have written this code for authentication.It works well till calling of function "a", control goes to function a but it ignores redirect line..I checked using alert that it executes "a" function. Why this is happening?

```
 $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
var userName = document.getElementById('uid').value;
var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/LoginNew.aspx/Authenticate",
    data : { 
        userName: userName ,
        password: password 
    },
    async : false, 
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : "json",
    success : a, 
    error : function(e) {
        alert(e.valueOf());
    }
});

function a() {
    window.location.href = "Login.aspx";
}
});
```

Comment: try to append full path instead of file name

Comment: @JayHardia..It directs well if I debug it in browser using fire bug..

Comment: please visit  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: @user1093183 - Sounds like loginbtn is a asp button, after postback it is reloading same page.

Comment: @afzalulh No its a html control

Answer (score 2):

```
success : a() //function is called like this
```

try using

```
success : function(){window.location.href = "Login.aspx"};
```

Comment: No its not working,I have to put only a..but this in not my problem It goes to the function "a"..If I put alert in "a" it works.but it does not go to the login.aspx page

Comment: `a` is the function reference, no need for another function wrapper.

Comment: Yes goes to Login.aspx page IF I put alert before function a eg. alert("");
                function a(result) {window.location.href = "Login.aspx";}

Comment: that's a wired behavior :/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.href` part, and you need to specify a path, something like this

```
window.location = "/Login.aspx";
```

Comment: @user1093183 that's weird. your code looks good and that is the only thing I can see. sorry.